# Interval arithmetic to correctly deal with end of month - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I need a function which will do interval arithmetic, dealing "correctly" with the different number of days in a month.  For my version of "correctly" - see below!

**First try**

```
select to_date('31-May-2014') + interval '1' months from dual
```

This returns an error, because there is no 31st June.  I understand that this behaviour is expected due to the ANSI standard.

**Second try**

```
select add_months(to_date('31-May-2014'),1)  from dual
```

This correctly (in my use case) returns 30th June 2014, which is great.  BUT

```
select add_months(to_date('28-Feb-2014'),1)  from dual
```

returns 31st March 2014, when I want 28th March 2014.

**Background**

This has to do with legal deadlines.  The deadlines are expressed in law as a number of months (say, 3) from a base date.  If the base date is last day of the month and three months later the month is longer, then the deadline does NOT extend to the end of the longer month (as per the add_months function).  However, if the base date is last day of the month and three months later the month is shorter, then the deadline expires on the last day of the shorter month.

**Question**

Is there a function that does what I need?

I have intervals (year to month) stored in a table, so preferably the function would look like:

add_interval_correctly(basedate DATE, intervaltoadd INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function, try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_LAW_MONTHS(Base IN DATE, Months IN NUMBER) 
    RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS

    DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH, -1839);

BEGIN
    RETURN Base + (Months * INTERVAL '1' MONTH);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH THEN
        RETURN ADD_MONTHS(Base, Months);
END;



SELECT 
    ADD_LAW_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-Feb-2014'),1), 
    ADD_LAW_MONTHS(TO_DATE('31-May-2014'),1)
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I have rewritten the function to take an INTERVAL data type rather than a NUMBER of months, but very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Wernfried's answer, above, but accepts INTERVAL data type rather than NUMBER of months.

```
create or replace FUNCTION ADD_LAW_MONTHS(Base IN DATE, IntervalToAdd IN INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH) 
RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS

    DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH, -1839);

BEGIN
    RETURN Base + IntervalToAdd;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DATE_NOT_VALID_FOR_MONTH THEN
        RETURN ADD_LAW_MONTHS(Base - 1, IntervalToAdd);
END;
```